# A little lost understanding how to use SSH key with Bitbucket

Tags: git, ssh, bitbucket

I understand that SSH keys are a way to identify trusted computers, without involving passwords but:

Do I need a different key for every project? because Bitbucket keeps telling **Someone has already registered that SSH key** when (*on the same machine*) I try to use the key I generate with `cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`.

I don't know if this is a Bitbucket thing, don't remember having this issue with Github. I'm using **Cloud9**. I'm totally confused. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

That error message is [only seen when you add an ssh key](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BBKB/SSH+key+is+already+registered).

But, you shouldn't have to add that key more than once: it represents who you are, and your account allows you to have as many "project" (Git or Hg repos) as you want.

Whenever you create a new repo, you don't have to add the ssh key: it is added once with your BitBucket account.

The only reason to have multiple keys is to [manage multiple identities](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Use+the+SSH+protocol+with+Bitbucket#UsetheSSHprotocolwithBitbucket-Singleormultipleidentitysetup).
For now, start simple, with one ssh public key on your account, and as many repo as you need.

Answer (score 0):

My bad. I was committing and pushing without doing `git init`. That's why it kept telling **Someone has already registered that SSH key**. Thanks @VonC.